# Day of Week Ascending Order in R

Tags: r

I am plotting a simple R graph with days of week in X axis and total sales in Y. I cannot figure out how to have x axis show days in ascending order. Any help is appreciated as I'm a newbie.

I tried below:
[image: image of plot]

```r
ggplot(df2, aes(x = df2$ends, y = df2$total.sale.price)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reorder levels of a factor without changing order of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375587/reorder-levels-of-a-factor-without-changing-order-of-values)

Comment: `stat_smooth(method = 'lm')` will only work with numeric variables, so it will not create a line here for you, if you need, you have to convert `ends` to numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Reorder your variable before running the plot. See below how to do it with base R.

```r
df2$ends <- factor(df2$ends, levels= c("Sunday", "Monday", 
    "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
```

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309564/reorder-factor-levels-by-day-of-the-week-in-r) question and response